# Mocha and Chai support

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to switch my JS unit tests from `jasmine` to `mocha` with `chai` but it annoys me Idea highlight `to` as `Unresolved variable`

[image]

I also installed libraries:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

chai chainable methods are correctly resolved to me after installing chai TypeScript stubs (`npm install @types/chai`):

[image]